# Is mysqli_stat() database or server specific?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When working on a webspace I assume that my databases also share the same MySQL-Server with other clients on the server.
In that case, are the fields from `mysqli_stat()` database specific information or server specific information?

I can see from some of the defintions in [mysqli::stat - PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.stat.php) that for example `Uptime` shows the "The number of seconds the MySQL **server** has been running.", which makes sense because my databases cannot have an individual independent uptime.

But since I am specifiying a database in `mysqli $link` like...

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
printf(mysqli_stat($link));
```

... are all other information also only regarding the sql server?

For example: Is `Questions` (another output of `mysqli_stat()`) the number of queries for the specified **database** or for the entire **server**?

Comment: Nothing in the documentation hints that anything returned is database-specific. The return value is *"A string describing the server status."* so I think the only right answer is that these values are global for the server.

Comment: That is true, thank you for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_stat()` gives you information about the mysqli server you are currently connected to, not a specific database you have selected.

All this information including number of "questions" is for all the databases on that MySQL server instance.

Answer (score -1):

`mysqli_stat()` is a database-server sepecific command. That being said it gives the stat of the server. If you're using same server with different clients, then it will give the status of whole server.

Although it is very unlikely that on shared hosting environment, you'll get a shared database server. Generally, all the host providers provide individual server to each of their client.

To anser specifically, it is a server specific command.

Comment: Not really what the question was asking.